# Dereferencing void pointers

Tags: c, arrays, void-pointers, dereference

In the hope of gaining a better understanding of the answers
given in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13618012/creating-a-generic-circular-buffer) post, can someone please explain to me if the
following circular buffer implementation is possible, and if
not, why not.

```
#define CB_TYPE_CHAR     0
#define CB_TYPE_FLOAT    1

...

typedef struct CBUFF
{
    uint16 total;       /* Total number of array elements */
    uint16 size;        /* Size of each array element */
    uint16 type;        /* Array element type */
    uint16 used;        /* Number of array elements in use */
    uint16 start;       /* Array index of first unread element */
    void *elements;     /* Pointer to array of elements */
} CBUFF;

...

void cbRead(CBUFF *buffer, void *element)
{
    if (buffer->type == CB_TYPE_CHAR)
    {
    /* The RHS of this statement is the problem */
        *(char*)element = *(buffer->elements[buffer->start]);
    }

    /* Other cases will go here */

    buffer->start = (buffer->start + 1) % buffer->total;

    --buffer->used;
}
```

I understand that the LHS must be cast to char so that I can
dereference the void pointer. I also understand that this code
fragment:

```
buffer->elements[buffer->start]
```

gives the address of the 'buffer->start' element of the elements
array, which I also want to dereference in order to get to the
content of that address. Or at least that's what I take from
K&R.

Given all that, how do I tell the compiler that the content of
the memory at that address is a char, and that it is okay to
dereference it? There is something going on here I just don't
understand.

Comment: This code does not compile, does it? The `*(buffer->elements[buffer->start])` is a dereference of a `void*`.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: That's what his question is in regards to.  I think he pulled the left hand side from K&R without fully understanding what it does.

Comment: Zack, is the 'type' of your generic buffer fixed once it is initialized and allocated? If so, you may be well served with a `union` of different pointer types to forego all the pointer casting.

Comment: Thats a great idea - I have never had to use a union before, and had forgotten all about them. I had better go do some reading - thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`buffer->elements` is also a `void *` so you need to cast it before you can do anything with it:

```
*(char*)element = ((char *)buffer->elements)[buffer->start];
```

Comment: Thanks Chris. I did not realize that such a construction was possible. Am I right in reading this as telling the compiler that the buffer->elements array contains chars, and to then get the contents of the buffer->start nth entry?

Comment: @Zack: yes, that is exactly correct.  Arrays in C are really treated like a pointers to their first element in most ways, so you can cast it to a different pointer type and get the compiler to treat it as if it was a different array type.

Answer (score 5):

> Given all that, how do I tell the compiler that the content of the memory at that address is a char, and that it is okay to dereference it?

Well, you've already done it on the LHS of that line:

```
*(char*)element = *(buffer->elements[buffer->start]);
```

To derefence `buffer->elements[n]` you will need to cast that as well.

```
*(char*)element = *((char*)buffer->elements)[buffer->start];
```

Now the question is whether or not that cast is correct.  I can't tell you that as you did not post the initialization of `buffer->elements`.

Comment: Thanks Ed. I guess I was confused by all the stuff on the RHS. With regards to the initialization, it is done in a function that creates the buffer dynamically, sets the value of a few members, and then buffer->elements = calloc(total, sizeof(size));