# void pointer dereferencing

Tags: c, pointers, void-pointers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Dereferencing void pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13694753/dereferencing-void-pointers)

I have a function call this way:

```
void foo(void *context)   //function prototype
..
..
..
main()
{
.
.
foo(&(ptr->block));  //where ptr->block is of type integer.
.
.
.
void foo(void *context)
{
 Here I try to use the ptr->block but am having problems. I have tried 

 if((int *)context ==1)  
  ..
  ..
}
```

I am typecasting it back to int in the function to use it. Am I dereferencing it wrong inside the foo() function?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
if((int *)context ==1)
```

you want this instead:

```
if(*(int *)context ==1)
```

You were casting to a pointer to `int` but what you actually want is to actually access the `int` so you need to dereference the pointer.

Answer (score 3):

You didn't typecast it to `int`, you typecast it to `int *`, and then didn't dereference it.  Try:

```
if (*(int *)context == 1)
```

Comment: Thanks for the instant reply! SO folks are just too good :-)

Answer (score 0):

when you want to access the value, just casting the pointer wont help you..

`(*(int*)context == 1)` will solve your issue..